# Speeding up torch.save

Tags: serialization, pytorch

As part of a training loop, I store a checkpoint of my model each time the validation score for an epoch improves as is commonly done:

```
if dice_score > best_dice_score:
    model_state = {
        "epoch": epoch,
        "model_state_dict": self.model.state_dict(),
        "score": dice_score
    }

    self.best_epoch = epoch
    best_dice_score = dice_score

    torch.save(model_state, "somefile.pt")
```

It works fine. However,it's really slow. The checkpoint file is about 750 MBs and is written to an SSD. This takes roughly 30% of the total train time, which I would like to reduce. How can this be done?

Comment: How can you compute the `dice_score`, if it's returned by the model, it may bring all computing graphs which makes your weight file heavier.

Comment: @CuCaRot In this case, it's a plain float which is the result of calling .item() on a pytorch tensor returned by some loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the real estimated time for saving the model?
If you are using SSD, the writing time would be under 1 sec.

Some other scripts would slow your entire training time, such as dataloader on each epoch.

Comment: I did not directly profile the code. I agree that the SSD is probably not the bottleneck. However, over the course of training, some epochs achieve a new best score and most do not. Those that do not achieve a new best score and thus do not save to disk complete much faster than the others.

Comment: Then, it would be related to the external disk (ex: writing file through ssh connections) or permissions. Your script for model saving is so comprehensive that there are no errors present.
How about grant root permission to current user or check the cpu usages during saving models?